# If $\dim H=\infty$, does there always exist a positive compact operator $T$ with infinite rank and $\|T\|\leq1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, compact-operators

If $H$ is an infinite dimensional (not necessarily separable) Hilbert space with $\dim H=\infty$, does there always exist a positive (i.e. self-adjoint and spectrum contained in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$) compact operator $T$ with infinite rank and $\|T\|\leq1$?

I was trying to construct one with an orthonormal basis $E$, but I ended up with the identity operator $I\colon H\to H$, which is not compact.

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean by "positive" operator?

Comment: @A.Salguero-Alarcón I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is your infinite-dimensional finite space, let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal sequence (it does not need to be a basis, just norm-one vectors which are pairwise orthogonal).

The operator

$$T:H \to H \quad , \quad T(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n \langle x|e_n\rangle e_n$$

where $(\lambda_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers converging to $ 0$, is compact and self-adjoint. Its eigenvalues are $(\lambda_n)$ and $0$, in case $(e_n)$ is not a basis. Now for positivity, just pick $\lambda_n=\frac1n$, for example.

For computing the norm of $T$ you can use Bessel's inequality:

$$\left\|\sum_n \lambda_n \langle x|e_n \rangle e_n\right\|^2 \leq \max |\lambda_n|^2 \cdot \sum_n  \langle x|e_n \rangle^2 \leq \max|\lambda_n|^2 \cdot \|x\|^2 $$

so in this case it is $\|T\|=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I see your point. I'm having issues with computing $\|T\|$. Is it $\leq1$?

Comment: I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Calculix You might note that $||T||\le1$ implies $||G||<1$ if $G=\frac12  T$...